# Regex for checking if string ends with [0-8] returns false

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to check if a string ends with a number between 0 and 8. Why is this regex returning false

```
String time = "" + new Date().getTime();// 1394205719160
if(time.endsWith("[0-8]"))//false
```

Comment: endsWith checks for a String match, not a regular expression match. See the answers for alternatives.

Comment: I'm not particularly sure of the reasons for downvotes on this question. The OP provided current code, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this instead:

```
if (time.matches(".*[0-8]$"))
```

or probably more efficient:

```
char lastChar = time.charAt(time.length() - 1);
if (lastChar >= '0' && lastChar <= '8') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `String.endsWith` does not accept regex,
it treats your input literally as the String `[0-8]`
not as the regex `[0-8]`.

Comment: @code578841441 Seems others already provided the alternative.